# Why does the Shanghai Maglev train cabin have a power bar and a portable fan?

Tags: trains, china, safety, shanghai

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_maglev_train#Operation) page for the Shanghai Maglev train depicts the train cabin:

[image]

The power bar and portable fan (on the left) look slapdash, and makes me doubt this train's safety.

Comment: Is there any reason why you think that a portable fan has any relevance for the train's safety?

Comment: How sure are we that the power bar and portable fan are standard features?

Comment: I'm curious about the filing cabinet and office chair (foreground, left). I think this might be a simulator.

Comment: @CannonFodder There are other similar pictures floating around the net, where you can also look out of the windows onto the track. The pictures seem genuine enough. Some drivers, perhaps the more senior ones, are even using a portable A/C unit and not merely a boring fan.

Comment: It's been in service for over twelve years without a major incident and you doubt it's safety?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not primarily about travel.

Comment: @CannonFodder that was my first impression too, but there are videos that show similar situation on actual trains. The model of the fan varies :-)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo This would directly contravene safety regulations on most trains as such unsecured equipment would become a projectile in a crash, and even if they didn't hit anybody, would impede egress. For example, the British [Railway Group Standard GM/RT2100](https://www.rssb.co.uk/rgs/standards/GMRT2100%20Iss%205.pdf) says "6.1.4.1 Except for trolleys being used for the provision of an at-seat service (see 6.7.5), there shall be no loose items of furniture or equipment," and further specifies inertial load requirements for their attachment.

Comment: I'm more surprised it has a driver's cab at all. There can't be much for a human driver to do at those speeds.

Comment: @user71659 British trains are not 'most trains', but nevertheless, I don't see any issue here. A passenger train is on purpose full with loose objects, namely the passengers and their luggage, which will cause much more damage in case of crash, than the fan in this picture.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Nope. Read section 6.2 and 6.8. They detail how passengers are retained and injury measures, such as head impact criterion, in a crash and how luggage is retained. Engineers do this for a living, they aren’t dumb. And the preface explains how this is harmonized with EU regulations. (Loading for example is a EN standard)

Comment: @user71659 I don't have to read the British requirements to know what everyone can see and observe when travelling by train in Europe. Train passenger are generally not (or never) using seat belts and can move freely around. Luggage, especially larger or heavier objects placed on overhead racks are obvious dangers in case of a crash or derailment, but also smaller items located on your seat table, e.g. laptops, can be dangerous enough. Since the risks are so low, these dangers are put up with for practical reasons.